# Safari Extension, Fluid App

Tags: safari, fluid, safari-extension

I've written a [simple extension for Safari](http://codaset.com/robwilkerson/add-to-google-reader) that captures clicks on the RSS button in the address bar (calls to the feed:// protocol) and redirects to Google Reader instead of Safari's feed reader. If, however, the user has a Fluid app (one that opens Google Reader) set as their default feed reader [the intercept doesn't work](http://codaset.com/robwilkerson/add-to-google-reader/tickets/1).

Is there any known way to capture a request that's being sent to a different app?  The extension currently keys on `document.beforeload()`, but if the document is being opened in a new "app", it's never reached, of course.

Is there a different event I can catch? I haven't found a comprehensive list of events that extensions can catch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extensions are a part of Safari not webkit, so safari extensions aren't available in other apps that embed webkit (like Fluid).